# Custom Writable class in hadoop for multiple double values

Tags: java, class, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to emit 4 numeric values as key.
I wrote custom writable Comparable class for the same but I am stuck with compare() method
there are several solutions mentioned in stackoverflow site. But that didn't solve my issue.

My writableCoparable class is

```
public class DimensionWritable implements WritableComparable {
    private double keyRow;
    private double keyCol;

    private double valRow;
    private double valCol;


    public  DimensionWritable(double keyRow, double keyCol,double valRow, double valCol) {
        set(keyRow, keyCol,valRow,valCol);
    }
    public void set(double keyRow, double keyCol,double valRow, double valCol) {
        //row dimension
        this.keyRow = keyRow;
        this.keyCol = keyCol;
        //column dimension
        this.valRow = valRow;
        this.valCol = valCol;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeDouble(keyRow);
        out.writeDouble(keyCol);

        out.writeDouble(valRow);
        out.writeDouble(valCol);
    }
    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        keyRow = in.readDouble();
        keyCol = in.readDouble();

        valRow = in.readDouble();
        valCol = in.readDouble();
    }
    /**
     * @return the keyRow
     */
    public double getKeyRow() {
        return keyRow;
    }
    /**
     * @param keyRow the keyRow to set
     */
    public void setKeyRow(double keyRow) {
        this.keyRow = keyRow;
    }
    /**
     * @return the keyCol
     */
    public double getKeyCol() {
        return keyCol;
    }
    /**
     * @param keyCol the keyCol to set
     */
    public void setKeyCol(double keyCol) {
        this.keyCol = keyCol;
    }
    /**
     * @return the valRow
     */
    public double getValRow() {
        return valRow;
    }
    /**
     * @param valRow the valRow to set
     */
    public void setValRow(double valRow) {
        this.valRow = valRow;
    }
    /**
     * @return the valCol
     */
    public double getValCol() {
        return valCol;
    }
    /**
     * @param valCol the valCol to set
     */
    public void setValCol(double valCol) {
        this.valCol = valCol;
    }

    //compare - confusing

}
```

Excatly what is the logic behind the compare statement- it is the exchange of keys in Hadoop right?

How to implement same for the above 4 double values.

**UPDATE**
I edited my code as "**isnot2bad**" said
But showing

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: edu.am.bigdata.svmmodel.DimensionWritable.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:404)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: edu.am.bigdata.svmmodel.DimensionWritable.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator.newKey(WritableComparator.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator.<init>(WritableComparator.java:99)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator.get(WritableComparator.java:55)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getOutputKeyComparator(JobConf.java:819)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.init(MapTask.java:836)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.createSortingCollector(MapTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.access$100(MapTask.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:584)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:330)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: edu.am.bigdata.svmmodel.DimensionWritable.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2721)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2002)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:122)
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: The stack trace posted in your update does not have anything to do with the original question about comparable. I assume your key class does not have a default constructor.

Comment: I added a default constructor Now my problem is solved .

Comment: For the future reader like me who gets directed here, I'd also warn you of making your WritableComparable implementation an inner class (in my case, it was an inner class of my mapper). I got the same exceptions as above. When I moved it to a class of it's own, it worked fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use your type as a key in Hadoop, it has to be comparable, (your type must be [totally ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)), i.e. two instances `a` and `b` of `DimensionWritable` must be either equal, or `a` must be greater or less than `b` (whatever that means is up to the implementation).

By implementing `compareTo` you define how instances can be [naturally compared to each other](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). This is done by comparing the fields of the instances to compare:

```
public int compareTo(DimensionWritable o) { 
    int c = Double.compare(this.keyRow, o.keyRow);
    if (c != 0) return c;
    c = Double.compare(this.keyCol, o.keyCol);
    if (c != 0) return c;
    c = Double.compare(this.valRow, o.valRow);
    if (c != 0) return c;
    c = Double.compare(this.valCol, o.valCol);
    return c;
}
```

Note, that `hashCode` must also be implemented, as it must be conform to your definition of equality (two instances that are considered equal according to `compareTo` should have the same hash code), and because Hadoop requires the hash code of a key to be [constant across different JVMs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/WritableComparable.html). So again we use the fields to compute a hash code:

```
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + Double.hashCode(keyRow);
    result = prime * result + Double.hashCode(keyCol);
    result = prime * result + Double.hashCode(valRow);
    result = prime * result + Double.hashCode(valCol);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Normally I am generating hashcode and equals through eclipse.I think that is fine.